# How can I import external Amazon S3 bucket data into BigQuery? Tried Data Transfer but got access error despite having correct permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I tried to import data from an external Amazon S3 bucket (the Dynamic Yield Daily Activity Stream, as it happens) into BigQuery by using the Data Transfer tab.

I created a new data set in my project and created an empty table with no schema (since the s3 data is Parquet, so am I right that I don't need to add a schema to the table?).

I then made a new data transfer with the S3 bucket credentials, selecting my new data set and table as the destination. I have tried multiple times but I get the same error, "Failed to obtain the location of the source S3 bucket. Additional details: Access Denied"

However, when checking with the owner of the bucket they have confirmed 100% that I do have the correct access, and on their end they have successfully pulled data from the bucket. I have been able to pull data from the bucket using Cloudberry Explorer myself too, with the same credentials.

So what have I done wrong? Is it because I didn't define the table schema? Or something else? Maybe the data set location is wrong? What else could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You're going to hate me saying it, but still sounds like a permissions issue.  Could be as simple as formatting of the bucket address, or something like that.  If you'd like a little more control of the process, you could transfer from s3->gcs first, then make the table on that file.  https://cloud.google.com/architecture/transferring-data-from-amazon-s3-to-cloud-storage-using-vpc-service-controls-and-storage-transfer-service

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's very welcome. One thing I tried RE the format of the bucket address was adding a / to the URI, because the owner of the bucket advised that without this it might throw an access issue, but unfortunately this didn't help. Are there any other things I could try doing with the URI format? Also I'll look into the s3->gcs transfer, thanks.

Comment: Hi there, one another option I could think of is the transfer protocol used here - I am thinking this could be https protocol which means you will need to allow port 443 in gcp vpc originating from aws region specific cidr ranges.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [BigQuery Documentation for Amazon S3 transfers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/s3-transfer#before_you_begin), you *do* need the schema definition for the table.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an access issue. It can stem from two places though:

- Your Access Key ID and Secret are incorrect
- Your S3 URI is incorrect

What does your S3 URI look like? Sometimes access is given to an individual "folder" or object rather than a whole bucket.

I get the exact same error when accessing an incorrect S3 bucket with a valid ID and Key.

[image: Transfer Error]

And to confirm the table needs to be created ahead of time:

[image]

And finally, since you're using parquet it does work with an empty schemaless table:
[image]

*I used a star notation to grab the file: s3://mys3bucket/*